# How to simplify quotient and mod in integer domain

Tags: simplifying-expressions, modular-arithmetic

I want to simplify `(a*32 + a%32)/32`, and a is integer.

So I write:

```
Simplify[Quotient[a*32 + Mod[a, 32], 32], Element[a, PositiveIntegers]]
```

However it gives me:

```
Quotient[32 a + Mod[a, 32], 32]
```

and I expect to see `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a bug.

```
 Simplify[Quotient[32 a + Mod[a, Range[32], 0], 32, 0], 
 Assumptions -> Element[a, PositiveIntegers]]
      
    (* {a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, \
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, Quotient[32 a + Mod[a, 32, 0], 32, 0]} *)
```